# TypeError: use() got an unexpected keyword argument 'warn' when importing matplotlib

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, r-markdown

I am attempting to learn R markdown / notebook to implement chunks of code which are R and Python. I can use R to a reasonable standard, but I am new to Python. I have downloaded R markdown to R studio and followed the prompts to download miniconda and did so.

I wanted to make a basic plot to see if it is working.

I click 'insert a new Python chunk'

Then copy and paste the following code into a 'Python chunk', which worked fine in Python using the Spyder environment.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
x = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
y = [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 15] 
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The following error is returned:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: use() got an unexpected keyword argument 'warn'
```

I had installed matplotlib using the following in an r chunk:

```
library(reticulate)
py_install("matplotlib")
```

I have tried pasting this chunk into a Python chunk and an R chunk with:

```
{r,engine='python'}
```

But to no avail. I can't see anyone having the same error or a guide specifying how to be able to import from Python, it all seems to show these chunks working straight out of the box. Apologies if I am missing something glaringly obvious. I have made sure all other versions of Python are uninstalled. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, as I one day hope to be able to integrate Python, R and bash scripts in this thing!

***Session info***:

```
Windows 10, R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29), R Studio Version 1.2.5001. R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.28      reticulate_1.16

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3  Matrix_1.2-18   tools_3.6.3     rappdirs_0.3.1 
[5] Rcpp_1.0.4.6    grid_3.6.3      jsonlite_1.6.1  xfun_0.9       
[9] lattice_0.20-38
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the exact same error when using reticulate and matplotlib.

I fixed it by downgrading my matplotlib version, e.g.:

```
pip install matplotlib==3.2
```

You can verify that matplotlib has been downgraded by running `pip freeze` and finding the matplotlib entry. It should look like `matplotlib==3.2.0`. (maybe try doing this from r, so you can be sure that you're working with the correct python installation).

I think this issue is caused by the 'warn' parameter being removed from a matplotlib function in recent versions of matplotlib, and R/reticulate assumes the older behaviour of the function.

Comment: This absolutely worked thank you - I had to become familiar with using pip install on command line (don't do much of this in R) to remove the old matplotlib and install the older version using the code you suggested. Sadly without 15 reputation I cant even upvote your answer! Will contact the reticulate people now and try to prevent more noobs like myself falling victim.

Comment: @Honk, awesome, I had the same problem and now Python runs again in RStudio. Cheerio, Franco

Comment: That also worked for me, although we can see now a deprecation warning:

`sys:1: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The 'warn' parameter of use() is deprecated since Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.  If any parameter follows 'warn', they should be pass as keyword, not positionally.`