# TypeError: use() got an unexpected keyword argument 'warn'

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, compiler-errors, data-science

I am trying to learn about Tables and while importing datascience library as:

```
from datascience import *
```

Or by

```
import datascience as ds
```

I get an error saying

> *TypeError: use() got an unexpected keyword argument 'warn'*

I get this error in module: *matplotlib.use()*

I have no any code other than that import line.
I'm using python version 3.8.5 and pip version 20.2.1. I installed the whole datascience libraries by:

**pip install datascience**

I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036394/failure-to-import-python-packages-using-r-markdown) solution in this topic but the error persisted after trying it. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never worked with this library before, but I did look at the documentation (https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.use)

It seems to me that you are passing a parameter (warn) that has been deprecated

Try this:

```
matplotlib.use(backend, force=True)
```

Edited:
The above mentioned solution didn't work for me.
As mentioned by @JustCarlos, I solved this issue by deleting the **warn** argument from line `matplotlib.use()` in two files **tables.py** and **util.py**. But I'm not sure if this deletion affects the other use of this library.

Comment: I have not used that method specifically as matplotlib.use(). My file only has a line ```import datascience``` and all arguments passes are happening in background during the import.

Comment: It looks like 'datascience' has a bug in it. They are using matplotlib.use('agg', warn=False) in tables.py and init.py. Try going to where those files are located and manually delete 'warn=False' and run `from datascience import * `. I tried it and the error disappeared.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I deleted the **warn** argument from ```matplotlib.use()``` line in two files by the way. One from **tables.py** and another from **util.py**. These files are located inside the Lib/sitepackages/datascience folder inside your python installation directory.

Comment: Hey, I just found out that using Matplotlib that way by deleting the ***warn*** argument forces the non-GUI use of Matplotlib. So, I can't plot charts, scatter diagrams nothing. How to solve this?

Comment: Never mind, I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-can-i-set-the-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python/34294056#34294056).