# Why i receive this error for Matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have install the latest version of Matplotlib 3.3.1 prob140 and data science libraries but when i load them this error occurs?
Anyone knows why does this happening?

```
from datascience import *
from prob140 import *
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-ab909b446210> in <module>
      1 import matplotlib
----> 2 from datascience import Table
      3 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 import numpy as np

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datascience/__init__.py in <module>
      1 from .version import __version__
      2 
----> 3 from .tables import *
      4 from .formats import *
      5 from .maps import *

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datascience/tables.py in <module>
     15 import numpy as np
     16 import matplotlib
---> 17 matplotlib.use('agg', warn=False)
     18 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     19 import pandas

TypeError: use() got an unexpected keyword argument 'warn'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: use() got an unexpected keyword argument 'warn' when importing matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036394/typeerror-use-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-warn-when-importing-matplo)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the argument warn that is deprecated. Also update your matplotlib to the latest version.

use this to force

```
matplotlib.use(backend, force=True)
```

For more information visit [for customizing](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html), [for use](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.use) and [for Backend Config](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is caused by the `warn` parameter being removed from a matplotlib function in recent versions of matplotlib  .

so try downgrading your matplotlib version to 3.2

```
pip install matplotlib==3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the version of `matplotlib` you installed has the keyword argument `warn` in the function use. If not, then I think the library `datasceience` uses a version of `matplotlib` (or was coded in a version) that does not match the version you installed.

If so, try downgrade or update the version of `matplotlib` you have installed, depending on the one `datascience` uses.